# How to generate an 8-bit random number in C>

Tags: c, random, types

```
int main(){

    uint8_t *wdata = NULL;
    wdata = calloc(5, sizeof(uint8_t));

    for (int j =0;j<5;j++){

        wdata[j] = rand();

    }

}
```

The `rand()` function generates 16 bits of data. How do I generate 8 bits of random values? Do I need to use a custom function for the same?

Comment: So rand returns 16bits, just use 8 of it and discard the rest.

Comment: What you've got will assign the least significant 8 bits of the 16-bit value that you say is returned by `rand()`.  Many versions of `rand()` will return 32-bit values, but that's a separate discussion.  The only problem with using the least significant 8 bits is that they may not be as random as you'd like — they might fail various tests of randomness.  How much that matters depends on what you're going to do next.  Most likely, you can simply use the code shown.  Failing that, you probably need a better pseudo-random number generator (PRNG) than `rand()`.

Comment: In exactly what way did this cause a problem? Did you just assume that your code is not working?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If you discard some of the random value by a power of 2, it'll still be an even distribution of randomness, won't it? e.g. `rand() % 16`, `rand() % 32`, `rand() % 64`, etc.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418113/lack-of-randomness-in-c-rand and especially links from it, such as to the paper by Marsaglia (sp?).

Comment: @fiddling: if rand is implemented with a.linear congruential generator, then the period of rand%2**i is 2**i, which is not very random for small `i`.

Answer (score 4):

> How to generate an 8 bit random number in C

Given code such as

```
uint8_t *wdata = calloc( 5, sizeof( uint8_t ) );
```

something like

```
for ( int j = 0;j < 5; j++ )
{
    wdata[ j ] = rand();
}
```

will work fine.

Integer assignment to an unsigned value truncates, which is exactly what you want.  See [6.5.16.1 Simple assignment of the C Standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1).

Note that `RAND_MAX` is guaranteed by [**7.22.2 Pseudo-random sequence generation functions**, paragraph 5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.2.1p5) to be at least 32767, which is "wider" than 8 bits, so the result is guaranteed to "fill up" an 8-bit variable.

Comment: Yes, but, http://c-faq.com/lib/notveryrand.html. See http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html.

Comment: @NeilEdelman A poor PRNG is a poor PRNG, and when the modulo value is much less than the maximum result from the PRNG the modulo operation itself won't add any measurable bias to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Because 8 bit number can contain maximum `0`-`255`. so if i divide `rand()%256` we get 8 bit random number.

```
  int main(){
    uint8_t *wdata = NULL;
    wdata = calloc(5, sizeof(uint8_t));
    for (int j =0;j<5;j++){
        wdata[j] = rand()%256;
   }
}
```

for more randomness you use some prime number add or subtract difference after dividing from `256`.

Comment: Since they are unsigned 8 bit numbers, `rand()%256` and `rand()` produce the same thing; although, it may be some benefit for readability.

Comment: rand(void) returns a pseudo-random number in the range of 0 to RAND_MAX. RAND_MAX is a constant whose default value may vary between implementations but it is granted to be at least 32767.